Combine html styling of markdown cell titles and neat display in table of contents
I like to style headings in jupyter notebooks using html like this:
# <div class="alert alert-info">Part 2: Line plots

However this then displays the html tags in the table of contents, which becomes difficult to read

Is there a way how to have both, i. e. styled titles in the notebook and neat display of title text in table of contents?
